# Application stops on back button in new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

I have this application, that have a listView, and when I click in a item on listView, it opens a new activity. That works fine!

But, if I open the new activity and than press the "back button" the application "Unfortunately, has stopped".

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

First activity:

> public class AndroidSQLite extends Activity {         private SQLiteAdapter
>   mySQLiteAdapter;
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>     ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
>
>     mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
>     mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
>
>     Cursor cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
>     startManagingCursor(cursor);
>
>     String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_NOME,SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID};
>     int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text,R.id.id};
>
>     SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter =
>      new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
>
>     listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
>
>     listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
>                 long id) {
>
>           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), id + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
>           Intent details = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailsPassword.class);
>           startActivity(details);
>
>         }
>     });
>
>     mySQLiteAdapter.close();
> } }
> ```

Second Activity:

> public class DetailsPassword extends Activity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>   TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
>   text.setText("Text to show");
>   setContentView(text);
> } }
> ```

// ===== EDITED =====

here is the Stack Track

> 10-30 08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-30 08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.example.sqliteexemple2/com.example.sqliteexemple2.AndroidSQLite}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed
>   cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4180a370 10-30
>   08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2701)
>   10-30 08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
>   10-30 08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1250)
>   10-30 08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-30
>   08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-30 08:55:05.744:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28046):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931) 10-30
>   08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-30
>   08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-30 08:55:05.744:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28046):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>   10-30 08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558) 10-30
>   08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-30 08:55:05.744:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28046): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   trying to requery an already closed cursor 
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4180a370 10-30 08:55:05.744:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28046):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5051) 10-30
>   08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5074) 10-30
>   08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2691)
>   10-30 08:55:05.744: E/AndroidRuntime(28046):  ... 10 more

Comment: What is the stack trace? Please post here.

Comment: Sorry, but, how I get the stack trace? I'm new on android development. And putting `this` instead `getApplicationContext()`, I got the same error!

Comment: You can find the stack trace in the 'LogCat' view in Eclipse. Just copy/paste the red lines containing details about your error.

Comment: I posted in the question, please, check up there.

Comment: you close cursor returned by SQLiteAdapter.queueAll prolly in mySQLiteAdapter.close();

Comment: Thank you Selvin, that is the answer! I commented the line `//mySQLiteAdapter.close();` and this worked! Can you post this as an answer for help someone else?

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida: But leaving your cursor (or database connection) opened is not a good practice. You should close it at some better place (may be at [Activity.onDestroy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()).

Comment: @Mudassir I'm thinking about open and close the cursor in the onResume() and onPause() of my MainActivity, is that a good practice?

Comment: @BrunoAlmeida: Yeah that will be good. But still, in that case if you access the cursor from `onCreate`, you may get the exception, because `onCreate` comes before `onResume` in the [execution path of activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the onKeyUp method

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    Intent backintntent= new Intent();
    intententregas.setClass(ThisActiviti.this, MainActivity.class);
            // you can add extra variables 
    // intent.putExtra("variable", Value);
    startActivity(backintntent);
    finish();
    return true;

}
```